# 林さんはピアノが好きで、子供にも小さいときからずっと、、、

Tags: meaning

> 林さんはピアノが好きで、子供にも小さいときからずっと
>
> 1. 習っていた。
> 2. 習わせていた。

For the statement above I chose 1 to be the correct answer, it was the wrong choice, 2 is the correct one.
Can someone explain why 1 is wrong and 2 is correct?

Meaning:

1. Hayashi-san loves playing the piano, he started at a young age and continued learning till now
2. Hayashi-san loves playing the piano, he started at a young age and continued forced learning till now

Comment: The key here is "にも" and "子供". にも is not the name of a cute clown fish! These questions and answers may help you out: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/search?q=%E3%81%AB%E3%82%82

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You answered incorrectly because you ignored 子供にも. Without this 子供にも, your first interpretation would have been just fine.

> 林さんはピアノが好きで、<del>子供にも</del>小さいときからずっと習っていた。
> Hayashi-san likes the piano, and he has been learning it ever since he was small.

However, the actual sentence *does* have 子供にも, and this 子供 refers to Hayashi-san's child. With 子供にも, the first choice starts to look very weird:

> 林さんはピアノが好きで、**子供にも**小さいときからずっと習っていた。
> Hayashi-san likes the piano, and he has been learning it **also from his child** ever since he (Hayashi-san) was small.
> <sub>(AにBを習う = to learn B from A)</sub>

This is "grammatically" correct, but semantically strange. It is impossible for a child to learn something from their own son or daughter who has not been born yet.

In your sentence, this 子供にも has a different role. That is, marking the agent (causee) of a causative verb. The following is the causative construction you needed to notice:

> 子供**に**(ピアノ**を**)習わせる
> to make his child learn (the piano)

And the following is what the original sentence actually means:

> 林さんはピアノが好きで、子供**に**も小さいときからずっと**習わせ**ていた。
> Hayashi-san likes the piano, and he has also **had his child learn it** ever since she was small.